# Chrome headless loades page differently than normal Chrome

Tags: puppeteer, google-chrome-headless

I have a simple script to use Puppter to crawl a webpage stopped working, so I started to debug.

I found if I launch my script by setting the *headless* option to *true*, my script can work as expected.

So I saved the page content and a screenshot, and I found they really are different than when the page is loaded with *headless* set to *false*.

I have enabled loading and executing JavaScript. It looks like the page can detect if it is loaded in headless mode and can render/behave differently.

Any idea how to troubleshoot if there's a bug in my script or that web page really can detect headless browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When launching the browser in headless mode, the user-agent changes to `HeadlessChrome`.
Thats what a web page can detect obviously, you need to set the user-agent manually using: [page.setUserAgent(userAgent)](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagesetuseragentuseragent).

Launch headless==true:

```
Mozilla/5.0 ... AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) HeadlessChrome/80.1.5.115 Safari/537.36
```

Launch headless==false:

```
Mozilla/5.0 ... AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.149 Safari/537.36
```